# Build navigation with routed URL in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm struggling with navigation in asp.net mvc and URLs.

When you are visiting your profile at Facebook, the url is facebook.com/yourusername. At your profile there is a menu with the following links: Timeline, About, Friends etc.

When you click on one of these links, for example `Photos`, the URL is changed to facebook.com/yourusername/Photos, and the photos are rendered. The menu described above are still there, and so also the profile picture and the cover picture. Its like a partial view has rendered viewing the photos.

I want to accomplish this effect in my project, but I don't know how to do it. I have tried to do it with `Partial view` but the problem is that the URL is not changed when the partial view is rendered.

How should I structure it?

My Index.cshtml that belongs to `Home-controller` looks like this:

```
div class="centering col-lg-7 logged_in_mainboxes" style="padding: 0; position: relative">

    <div class="col-lg-12 coverPicture" style="background-image: url('/Content/Images/@Model.CoverPicture');">
       <div id="image-cropper">
            <div class="cropit-preview"></div>         
            <h3 class="coverPicTextStyle">
                @Model.Name
            </h3>
            <button type="submit" id="uploadCoverpicture" class="btn_style_2 btn" style="position: absolute; bottom: 10px; right: 10px;">Upload</button>
            <button type="submit" id="crop" class="btn_style_2 btn" style="position: absolute; bottom: 50px; right: 10px; display: none;">Done</button>
            <input type="file" class="cropit-image-input" id="coverUpl" style="display: none;" />
        </div>
        <div class='progress' id="progress_div">
            <div class='bar' id='bar1'></div>
            <div class='percent' id='percent1'></div>
        </div>
        <input type="hidden" id="progress_width" value="0">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 pull-left">
        <div class="user_menu">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Wall","Wall","Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Music", "Music", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Photos", "Photos", "Home")</li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Videos", "Videos", "Home")></li>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-7 pull-left" style="margin-top: 15px;">

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 pull-right" style="border-left: 1px solid #ddd; margin-top: 15px; ">
        asdasd
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You could do that by defining routes - say `url: {username}/Photos` and `defaults { controller = "Photos", action = "Index" }` and redirect to that method, passing the user name (the menus etc would be just part of the layout)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: But I don't want that user specific menu to be a part of the Layout-file.

Comment: If its a user specific menu, then you generate it in the layout by using `@{ Html.RenderAction(...); }`, passing the username (or ID) to the a method that generates the menu items based on the user

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Sorry, I dont understand your solution. I have the all the layout of the profile inside my Index.html that belongs to the Home-controller. Check my updated question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Yes I have?

Comment: Now I do not understand you previous question - there is no 'user specific menu' in the view you have shown. And where is the link that you want to navigate to the `{username}/Photos` page? (do you mean `<li>@Html.ActionLink("Photos", "Photos", "Home")</li>`? - that's not even passing the username to the `Photos()` method)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: I want this: When you click on any of the links(Wall, Music, Photos...), I want a Wall-partial, Music-Partial, Photos-partial to render In my col-lg-7-div below. When the specified partial has renderd, I want the URL to change to the url for the partial view. So, If I click on the Wall link, the Wall-partialview should render inside the div, and the url should change from localhost123 to localhost123/Home/Wall

Ignore the {username} in the URL for now. That can be changed later.

Comment: For that you going to need a [Single Page Application](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application). Otherwise, you will need to follow the normal pattern and redirect to another page when you click on one of those links (and all the code in the view you have shown would be in the layout)

Comment: And ignore the answer by Bharath theorare - it does nothing to solve your problem :)

Comment: @StephenMuecke: It must be another way to solve this. Facebook Is not a single page application.

Comment: Then why not just redirect?

Comment: @StephenMuecke: And how should I do with the menu then? Coverpicture etc etc?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112556/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-bryan).

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Im still struggling with this. You said that I should move the menu into the layout file. But IF I do that, the menu Is displayed everywhere on every page? I don't want that. I assume that I must have different layouts to use in my Views?

I only want to show this menu when U are visiting a profile(a member of the site). The coverpicture, the menu, the profile picture should still be there when you click any of the links. Like on facebook. Where should I put this "Static" content that should always be visible when visiting a profile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would first start by grouping all he methods associated with the user in a `UserController` method which will include methods such as

```
public ActionResult Index(string username)
public ActionResult Photos(string username)
public ActionResult Music(string username)
```

etc, and the routing configuration as per your [subsequent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37358416/routing-in-asp-net-mvc-showing-username-in-url). and create a separate layout page hat will be used for each of these methods (say) `_UserLayout.cshtml` and each view for these methods will then include

```
@{ Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_UserLayout.cshtml"; }
```

In order to pass the username around(to the layout, and subsequently to the methods via the `ActionLink()` methods, create a base class (say)

```
public class UserBaseVM
{
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}
```

and all models used in these methods would derive from that base class (say)

```
public class UserPhotosVM : UserBaseVM
{ 
    public List<YourPhotoModel> Photos { get; set; }
    ....
```

Then in `_UserLayout.cshtml`, use the `UserName` property of `UserBaseVM` to generate your links

```
@model yourAssembly.UserBaseVM
... //add common menu/navigation elements
<div class="col-lg-12 pull-left">
    <div class="user_menu">
        <ul>
            <li>@Html.ActionLink("Photos", "Photos", new { userName = Model.UserName })</li>
            ....
```

Then your method would be

```
public ActionResult Photos(string userName)
{
    UserPhotosVM model = new UserPhotosVM()
    {
        UserName = userName,
        Photos = .....
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

A cleaner and more flexible solution would be to create a `[ChildActionOnly]` method that returns a partial view of the menu, for example

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult Menu(string userName)
{
    UserBaseVM model = new UserBaseVM(){ UserName = userName });
    ....
    return PartialView(model);
}
```

and in the `_UserLayout.cshtml` file, use

```
@{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", new { userName = Model.UserName });
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is you should implement routes in your application.

Create a class "RouteConfig" like this: Use `using System.Web.Routing;`

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        var route = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            namespaces: new string[] { "YourDomain.NameSpace.Controllers" }
        );
        route.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = true;
    }
}
```

Register the routes in your Global.asax file in Application_Start() method:

```
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

Now implement Session concept to redirect a user logged to your application and call it by using `OnAuthorization` method in your base controller.

If you to use partial view page, use:

```
@Html.Partial("_YourPartialViewPage", Model)
```

Use Ajax calls in your javascript method to pass data to the controller.

```
yourAjax({ url: '@Url.Content("~/YourController/YourControllerAction")', data: { headerId: id, }, success: successFunction });
```

Comment: Each language has its own way of compiling and interpreting. And this, is  a simple way of configuring routes in MVC and not a complex solution as you think. If you want to consider an example of using complexity in this. consider about multilingual and implementing localizations in your application.

Comment: Ok. But I don't see how the code you provided solves my problem? I already have the code that you specified, except the namespace part in the routes-file. How does the code you provided help me with my issues provided In my question?

Comment: Follow the solution completey. It should solve the problem. Check if you have done others and try to implement that if you have missed.